# Changing Properties in one object, changes in all, why?

Tags: class, properties, equals

I was coding a simple map creator when i noticed that some tiles were being changed in the general map and not in the localmap that would later be merged into the general map... so i began testing some things, and for some reason this happens. Why does it return the same if i changed the Type property?

any change made to any property of the first or the second Tile applies to both.

```
        Tile first = new Tile(new CoordInt(0, 0), tileType.Wall);//create first tile new Tile(new CoordInt(int,int), (Enum)tileType)
        Tile second = first;//NEW Tile second equals first
        second.SetType(tileType.Floor);//property Type of the Tile named second is set to Floor (property set to { get; private set; })
        Debug.Log(first.ToLongString());
        Debug.Log(second.ToLongString());
        Debug.Log(first == second);

        //Console
        //Tile at (0, 0) from room -1 is a Floor and is Neutral
        //You CANNOT walk in it
        //Tile at (0, 0) from room -1 is a Floor and is Neutral
        //You CANNOT walk in it
        //True

        //Why does this return the same, if i'm changing the property only of the Tile named second and not of both?
```

Comment: Please use proper formatting and indentation and don't just comment inside a code block instead of writing normally outside a code block.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a copy of the object. First and second reference the same object in memory. You could add a copy method to the class.

Comment: that explains why some other things been behaving strangely... thx